# Calling JavaObjects in JavaScript to Applet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, applet

I am looking for a way to to return a JavaObjects, which is saved in a Http Session, to an Applet. I am using JSP, so I am able to return Objects in the session by:

```
<%request.getAttribute("Object")%>;
```

So now I would like to return this Object to an applets Method with

```
document.applet.method(<%=request.getAttribute("Object")%>);
```

But this isn't working at all. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can simply refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession)

it shows u how can u use session object to carry object , try , it should work

Comment: But the point at my question is, that i can´t retrive this returned Object as a parameter to my applet.

Comment: Or asked different, if i am calling the Applets method with Javascript, i am just allowed to use Strings or Integer?