# How can I put an object (definied into a servlet) into a session to use it into a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

this is my first time that I work on a J2EE project and I have the following problem:

I have the following servlet that implement the **HttpServlet** interface.

```
public class Salwf extends HttpServlet {

    private String msg = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        StandardConfigurationFactory standardConfigurationFactory = new StandardConfigurationFactory();

        try {
            standardConfigurationFactory.init();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

        ConfigurationFactory.setInstance(standardConfigurationFactory);
    }

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoggerMDC.setup(req, res);
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        String service = req.getParameter("serv");

        char serviceId = Utility.getServizio(req.getParameter("serv"));

        // The collection that have to be shown in a table inside the JSP view:
        SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = this.getSalDettaglioList();

        gotoPage(ConfigurationFactory.getPropertiesPages().getProperty("pagina_salwf"), req, res);

        //String paginaDaLanciare = lanciaServizio(serviceId, req, res);
    }

    /*
    private String lanciaServizio(char num_servizio, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        HttpSession session;

    }
    */

    private void gotoPage(String address, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC
        logger.debug("gotoPage() | address: " + address);

        ServletContext ctx = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }

    private SalDettaglio[] getSalDettaglioList(){

        SalDettaglio[] salDettaglioArrayResult;

        List<SalDettaglio> salDettaglioList = new ArrayList<SalDettaglio>();

        List<RM> rmList = new ArrayList<RM>();

        RM rm1 = new RM("codiceRM1", "Andrea", "01/01/1014", "acqRiserva1", "consegnaFinale1", "descrizioneRM1", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
        RM rm2 = new RM("codiceRM2", "Andrea", "01/01/1014", "acqRiserva2", "consegnaFinale2", "descrizioneRM2", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));

        rmList.add(rm1);
        rmList.add(rm2);

        RM[] rmArray =  (RM[]) rmList.toArray();

        SalDettaglio salDettaglio1 = new SalDettaglio("codice1", "stato1", "01/01/2014", "01/06/2014", "Andrea",
                "Andrea", "Andrea", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), "fornitore1",
                "rmConRiserva1", "errore1", null, rmArray);

        SalDettaglio salDettaglio2 = new SalDettaglio("codice2", "stato2", "01/01/2014", "01/06/2014", "Andrea",
                "Andrea", "Andrea", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), "fornitore2",
                "rmConRiserva2", "errore2", null, rmArray);

        salDettaglioList.add(salDettaglio1);
        salDettaglioList.add(salDettaglio2);

        salDettaglioArrayResult = (SalDettaglio[]) salDettaglioList.toArray();

        return salDettaglioArrayResult;

    }

}
```

As you can see into the **service()** method I have this array definition:

```
SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio
```

Now I have to put it into session so that I can use it into a **JSP** view.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to put it in the session and not just the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("salDettaglio", salDettaglio);
```

This puts `salDettaglio` in the session and you can acces it with the attribute identifier `salDettaglio` keep in mind that it stores it as a plain `Object` so you'll have to cast in in the JSP if you are using sciplets.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession)

Answer (score 2):

Beware that Session's getAttribute / setAttribute methods are synchronized, but what you store with them is your responsibility. That means if you change a mutable field in the stored object that is not guaranteed to be seen by another thread. Since servlets are called by different threads from a thread-pool this can be a problem. To avoid this use either immutable objects or make your objects thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

create one session object and put your array into that session object and using sendRedirect() you can fwd your session through it..!!