# How to set session variable in jsp

Tags: jsp

## Edit the file web.xml session timeout value

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: How would you like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a variable in `session`, you need not edit `Web.xml`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String al="am session variable"
session.setAttribute("al", al);
```

and to access it , you can simply do `${sessionScope.al}`

Read [How do you store Java objects in HttpSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession)