# how we store value in session variable in jsp and acess to another page that session variable

Tags: jsp, session

I want to store value in session variable. We fetch value from
database and I want to show these values to another page in text fields.

```
<%=rs.getString("first_name") %>
```

How can we store this value in session and get another page?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set session attribute in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292940/how-to-set-session-attribute-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set session variable in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170025/how-to-set-session-variable-in-jsp)