# How to Store user data in a session using entityManager and jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa

I have a Login Form which a user sends over with there username and password. The form action points to a method in my WS class. I'm wondering how I can store the User that logs in in a session. I'm using JPA and hibernate to store the data in a MYSQL database.

I'm also using JBoss AS 7.1 in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the user that is logged in in a session, you must use the HTTP Session, not JPA/EntityManager or Hibernate.

For more information, refer to this question: [How do you store Java objects in HttpSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession)