# Java Spring session.getAttribute("test") is null

Tags: java, spring, httpsession

I have a problem with HttpSession, I do not have it 
I think I forget an Annotation or anything like this.
Do I need anywhere to do a session.create() ?

In UserController :

```
@Controller
public UserController{
    public ResponseHttp connection(User userSent, HttpSession session) {
        ResponseHttp responseHttp = new ResponseHttp();       

        //function to check login/mdp 
            if (check) {
                responseHttp.setSuccess(true);
                responseHttp.setMessage("Connection success");
                //some code 
               //
               //
               session.setAttribute("userId", 1); // this is an example
               System.out.println(session.getAttribute("userId")) // return 1
               return responseHttp;
            }
        }

        responseHttp.setSuccess(false);
        responseHttp.setMessage("Connection failed");

        return responseHttp;
    }
}
```

In another controller :

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    public void test(HttpSession session){
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("userId")) ; // return null
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 25-06-2017**

I tried to inject @HttpSession in both controllers
At connection I check the session like that :

```
if(httpSession.isNew()){
    System.out.println("New") // ok return new !
    System.out.println(httpSession.getId()); // A87AC018FD8DDA33B023FAA6C1C2D71C
}
```

In the other controller

```
if(httpSession.isNew()){
    System.out.println("New") //  it's returning new again
    System.out.println(httpSession.getId()); //  2FE08FB68EA53F7FEBB8143CFEE6A9EB
}else{
    System.our.println("not new")
}
```

Question: Why is not the same session ?

Comment: verify if both sessions are same by printing the session ids

Comment: what about your scope!

Comment: take a look to this link may be it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession

Comment: If you're testing it with something like `curl` or `postman` don't forget to pass  a JSESSIONID Cookie/url param between requests.

Comment: If they are not the same , what should i do ?

Comment: You are losing the cookie; how are you testing your application?