# try accesing entity class object properties in jsp with session tracking but it is showing error?

Tags: java, jsp

i am basically trying to do session tracking in index-2.jsp and using entity class object properties in all over my index-2.jsp to show user his/her name,email-id,phone no ,etc.

index-2.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
    <%
    if ((String) session.getAttribute("uId") != null) {
        System.out.print("session succesfully created");
        UserDetailsEntity user = OfyService.ofy().load().type(UserDetailsEntity.class)
                .id((String) session.getAttribute("uId")).now();
        System.out.println(user);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
    }
    %>
   </head>
   <body> <%=user.fName%>  /*here it is showing that user cant resoled to a type*/
   </body>
</html>
/* setting session in servlet */
```

servlet.java

```
if (user.checkIfUserAlreadyExist(uId)) {
    System.out.println("already exist with same id");
    resp.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
} else {
        System.out.println("user does not exist");
    if (user.checkIfConfirmPassIsSame(uPass, cPass)) {
        System.out.println("pass is same");

        user.registerUser(fName, lName, uId, uPass, mNo, addr1, addr2, bType, dateOfBirth);

        HttpSession ses=req.getSession();
        ses.setAttribute("uId", uId);
        resp.sendRedirect("index-2.jsp");
    } else {
        System.out.println("retypePassword");
        resp.sendRedirect("register.jsp");    
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: From your code i can't see where you save the `user` object in session or in request.

Comment: Take a look on this on how to save objects in session and how to use those objects in the jsp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766521/how-do-you-store-java-objects-in-httpsession.

Comment: HttpSession ses=req.getSession();    ses.setAttribute("user",user);    resp.sendRedirect(index-2.jsp);.                                     now in my index-2.jsp I am accessing it like.                <% UserDetailsEntity user =(UserDetailsEntity)Session.getAttribute("user")    %>     
  <%= user.fName%>  here it is. Showing user cannot resolved to a type