# Pass Database Connection from GWT App to Java Program

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, web, jndi

I have a web app built in GWT running in tomcat that accesses the database. On the same server, I have some server-side Java applications running that need to use the same database connection. These applications will be deployed as a war file alongside the GWT app.

Is there a way I can send the connection from the GWT app to these server-side apps?

This isn't a whole lot of information, I understand. To me, the problem is easy enough to understand, though I haven't found a solution yet. If you need anymore information, I'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, that the applications have to use the same jdbc connection string or is it more like a shared connection pool.
Is it a solution for you to have a datasource in the local jndi and use this in your applications as well as in the servlets?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this has nothing to do with GWT.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123657/how-can-i-share-a-variable-or-object-between-two-or-more-servlets)

[ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) provides a way of sharing objects among different servlets and even among diffrenet webapps

```
this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("sharedObject", shared); 
this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("sharedObject");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same connection in two different web apps. But if you mean to use same `connection pool` form which both the GWT and the other web app will fetch connections, then you need to configure the datasource at the application server level using `JNDI`

There are lots of JNDI tutorials using servlet in the internet.

Following is a link I found on using JNDI in GWT

http://humblecode.blogspot.in/2009/05/gwt-16-using-jndi-datasource.html